# Measure FPS methods

Tags: android

I've trying to do some customizations on Google Android Launcher (from Gingerbread 2.3.3 source).
However, when I run my custom Launcher on real device, it doesn't look smooth while I fling home screen left-right between screens.
I'm wondering what is the best method to calculate/measure FPS on home screen while flinging left-right?

Anyone get ideas to improve the Android Launcher 2.3.3 performance?
Appreciate everyone support :)

Answer (score 2):

[Mesure FPS]

If you have Android full source, Modify and build ViewRoot.java 
the file locates "/frameworks/base/core/Java/android/view/ViewRoot.java"

Edit line (false -> true )

```
private static final boolean SHOW_FPS = false;
```